# How to identify and find navels from human pics

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, pattern-recognition

I have a specific question and not sure what tools I can use to finish my projects. I know this may has been well solved, but I am quite new to the image recognition and detection area and don't know what tools I can use to productionize this work.

We are trying to find, for example, navels in humans pics:

1. I have 10000 body pics from different persons as the training set. All pics have shown their navels, but we don't resources to label them in these pics.
2. Given a pic of a different person, trying to find this person's navel in this pic within a very short time (e.g., less than 1 second). The accuracy must be very high.

I am wondering what tools I can use to do this work (the best is that has c++ implementation because we may want to productionize this project).

Comment: Are you asking for tools or algorithms? This site is about computer science, so we do algorithms, not tools.

Comment: 1. What approaches have you already tried or considered?  What research have you done?  2. If you're asking for algorithms, can you give us a few example pictures and what you want the algorithm to output on those pictures?  (and if you have tried an algorithm, show us what output it produces on those pictures and why it doesn't meet your needs?)  See also http://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/computer-vision/info (to be clear: I added this only just now, so you wouldn't have been able to see it when you composed your question).

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Sorry for the confusion. I added more comments in the first answer section.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you would want to find navels, sounds like a strange problem. Anyway, I would approach it using standard computer vision detection methods. Create a labelled dataset of navels. Then train a sliding window detector based on some visual features eg., Haar, SIFT, HOG. Now use your detector to find more examples of navels and add them to your dataset.

Comment: Can you give references for why this is likely to work (well)?

Comment: Well I don't think anyone has actually done this particular problem. But I do know that the methods I have described work very well for face detection and person detection. So I don't see why they won't work here. Perhaps it may be easier to detect a person and then estimate where the navel could be.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I actually work on a medical project of which I can't disclose the details. But I find this strange "navels" problem may be similar to what I want to describe:). I want to further clarify a little bit. The problem is that we don't have enough resource to label all the 10000 images. All of them have human body pics with navels. I probably can manually label 100. So what algorithm I can use to get a very high accurate model （because it will be used in hospitals).

Comment: Semi-superivised may be helpful, but I am not sure which one is the state of the art. Moreover, the structure may be quite complex, so in some cases, we may want to use deep learning, but I am not sure how deep learning can be combined with semi-supervised learning.